# System of equations based question in matrix form

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

If $\begin{bmatrix}1^2&2^2&3^2\\2^2&3^2&4^2\\3^2&4^2&5^2\\4^2&5^2&6^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\10\\\lambda\end{bmatrix}$,then $\lambda=$
$(A)17\hspace{1cm}(B)18\hspace{1cm}(C)19\hspace{1cm}(D)20$

---

I tried solving this question.
$1^2x+2^2y+3^2z=1$
$2^2x+3^2y+4^2z=4$
$3^2x+4^2y+5^2z=10$
I solved this system to get $x=\frac{25}{8},y=\frac{-5}{2},z=\frac{7}{8}$
$4^2x+5^2y+6^2z=\lambda$
I substituted $x,y,z$ in the above equation to get $\lambda=19$.
But this method is long and tedious.My book gives one method but that i cannot understand.Please help me understand this.Book's method is not self explanatory.
Book's solution:
$(n+3)^2=n^2-3(n+1)^2+3(n+2)^2$
$\lambda=1-3\times4+3\times 10=19$

---

OR if someone knows any better and elegant way to solve this question,please tell me,like using eigen values etc.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column of the matrix is of the form $[n^2,(n+1)^2,(n+2)^2,(n+3)^2]^T$. The book’s expansion of $(n+3)^2$ shows you that the third row is a linear combination of the first three, which means that $\lambda$ must be the same linear combination of the first three elements of the vector.

Comment: One has to wonder why the author of the book thinks that's an evident enough solution for the solutions in the back of the book.  What would lead the student to expand $(n+3)^2$ like that?  There must be something more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: @GregoryGrant It struck me as odd, too. Easy enough to work out in retrospect, but not something that might jump out at one at first glance.

Comment: Maybe the author is just being a smartass.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by row reducing the augmented matrix into echelon form. The augmented matrix is given by:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1^2&2^2&3^2&1\\
      2^2&3^2&4^2&4\\
      3^2&4^2&5^2&10\\
      4^2&5^2&6^2&\lambda\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Row reducing leads to:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1^2&2^2&3^2&1\\
      0&-7&-20&0\\
      0&0&\frac{8}{7}&1\\
      0&0&0&\lambda-19\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

This system is only consistent if $\lambda - 19 = 0$ , therefore $\lambda = 19$.

Comment: What you have done is essentially the same as his solution.  But what he's asking is for an explanation of the book's given solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer but I do notice that the equation $n^2-3(n+1)^2+3(n+2)^2=(n+3)^2$ shows that when $[x,y,z]=[1,-3,3]$ then the top three rows of the matrix times $[x,y,z]^T$ equals the (transpose of the) fourth row.  And it also equals $[1,4,10]^T$.  And the second equation is $[1,4,10]\times[1,-3,3]^T=\lambda$.